# Basic Prime Number generator

Tags: python, primes, mit-scratch

I've been trying to make a prime number generator in Python, basically porting [this](http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/978284/) Scratch project into Python terms, and then writing the primes into a text document.

For some reason though, it isn't working and I can't work out why, as it is just writing the numbers as it goes.

```
def primenumbers():
    j = 2
    f = open("primes.txt", "w")
    primes = []
    notprimes = []
    ask = input("how many primes? ")
    while len(primes) < int(ask):
        k = 2
        while not(k==j) or not(j%k==0):
            k = k + 1
        if k == j:
            primes.append(j)
            f.write(str(j)+"\n")
        else:
            notprimes.append(j)
#        if len(primes)%1000 == 0:
#            print("There have been " + str(len(primes)) + " primes counted so far")
        j = j + 1
    print("Primes written to file 'primes.txt', " + str(len(primes)) + " written")
    f.close
    return(" ")
```

So, the program asks the user for how many primes it should generate, and it should then repeat from k=2 to j = j+1 until that number of primes is reached.

Also, if possible, I should like the commented out IF statement to work, as when that was included it repeated what prime number it was on several times. 
EDIT: adding what happens when run

```
how many primes? 1500
There have been 1000 primes counted so far
There have been 1000 primes counted so far
There have been 1000 primes counted so far
There have been 1000 primes counted so far
There have been 1000 primes counted so far
There have been 1000 primes counted so far
There have been 1000 primes counted so far
There have been 1000 primes counted so far
Primes written to file 'primes.txt', 1500 written
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `while not(k==j) and not(j%k==0):` in place of `while not(k==j) or not(j%k==0):`
Then it will work fine.

I hope this is the code you are looking for:

```
def primenumbers():
    j = 2
    chk = 1
    f = open("primes.txt", "w")
    primes = []
    notprimes = []
    ask = input("how many primes? ")
    while len(primes) < int(ask):
        k = 2
        while not(k==j) and not(j%k==0):
            k = k + 1
        if k == j:
            primes.append(j)
            f.write(str(j)+"\n")
        else:
            notprimes.append(j)
        if len(primes) >= 1000*chk:
            chk = chk + 1
            print("There have been " + str(len(primes)) + " primes counted so far")
        j = j + 1
    print("Primes written to file 'primes.txt', " + str(len(primes)) + " written")
    f.close
    return(" ")
```

Comment: That works. Should it also work for the commented out section? EDIT:No it doesn't. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if u want to print which that prime number was found then u can print it inside 'if j==k:' case just before or after writing the prime number into text file. Accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: What I'm looking for in the commented section is every 1000 prime numbers the terminal says how many primes have been generated, because otherwise nothing is visually happening on the teminal. When the number of primes is 1500, there are 8 "There have been 1000 primes counted so far"s.

Comment: @Vipul For non-zero _k_, `k==j` implies `j%k==0`. That is because every non-zero number divides by itself. Given that _k_ ≥ 2, `while not(k==j) and not(j%k==0):` can be replaced by `while not(j%k==0):`; the two are functionally equivalent, but the latter is a _lot_ more readable and consequently more maintainable.